# Ошибка при запуске Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переустановка не помогла. Хотелось бы сохранить настройки, много чего настроено под себя.

[image: Ошибка при запуске Sublime Text]

---

Спасибо, удаление еммета через Package Control: Remove Package помогло. Попробую поставить начисто.

Comment: Там скорее всего ошибка с плагином Emmet

Comment: Да, это я понял, частично решается удалением папки с настройками эммета. Все запускается и работает до следующей перезагрузки.

Comment: то есть папка заново загружаться при перезагрузке?

Comment: Да, и как оказалось после закрытия редактора тоже.
Чтобы запустить его снова без ошибки мне нужно каждый раз удалять файлик еммета в папке Installed Packages. Фото Сверху приложил

Comment: Так удалите пакет Emmet

Comment: Попробуй удалить, запустить и удалить как я в ответе указал.

Comment: Нашли ответ? У меня такая же проблема но почему то нету даже папки Installed Packages

Answer (score 0):

1. Запускаем `Ctrl + Shift + P`
2. Ищем `Package Control: Remove Package`
3. Появляется список установленных у Вас плагинов. Выбираете нужный.